# Set WorkingDirectory using a variable

Tags: systemd

How can I set the Service WorkingDirectory using an environment variable?  Here is an example service config:

```
[Service]
Environment=MYWORKINGDIR=/tmp
WorkingDirectory=${MYWORKINGDIR}
```

This generates an error along the lines of `not an absolute path`. Adding a slash to the start "fixes" that error, but the path is still not found:

```
[Service]
Environment=MYWORKINGDIR=/tmp
WorkingDirectory=/${MYWORKINGDIR}
```

Is this even possible? Documentation isn't clear on which directives can/can't use env variables.

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

No, It's not possible.

You can use:

- `~`
- absolute directory path
- `-` absolute directory path

Also, `WorkingDirectory` understands [specifiers](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers).

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found was to point WorkingDirectory= to symlink, and change the symlink prior to starting the service.

I know it is not the same; but solved the problem that I was trying to solve with same approach of yours.

Answer (score 0):

For all late-comers I have a useful solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742644/92366

In short, if you don't need anything too complicated, you could instead use:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "cd \"/path/${variable_subpath}/\";echo \"${PWD}\";"
```