# Cannot change directory (cd) or use Working Directory Systemd Exec commands

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, docker, startup

I am trying to get a startup script (**systemd service)** for `docker-compose containers`.

I am struggling to get it working, and have made changes and changes; with some things working, and other things not working as expected, specifically how *environment variables* work with systemd configurations.

```
# named `dc-mag235.service`
[Unit]
Description=Magento 2.3.5 Docker-Compose Containers
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/docker/_systemd.startups_/mag2.35.env.file
#PassEnvironment=$DCFOLDER
Type=simple
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=${DCFOLDER}
ExecStartPre=mkdir -p ${LOGFOLDER}
ExecStartPre=echo ${DCFOLDER}
ExecStartPre=echo Starting Docker-compose service for ${DESCRIPTION}...
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose start
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose restart
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
DESCRIPTION=Magento 2.3.5 Docker-Compose Containers
LOGFOLDER=/var/www/docker/_initlogs_
LOGFILE=$LOGFOLDER/dc-mag235.startup.log
DCFOLDER=/var/www/docker/magento2-docker-full-supervisord-expanded/release-magento2.35
```

Trying to use `WorkingDirectory` with the variable `$DCFOLDER`:
*When I remove `PassEnvironment` I get the same error mentioned here*:

```
sudo service dc-mag235 status
/etc/systemd/system/dc-glo-mag235.service:8: Invalid environment name for PassEnvironment, ignoring: $DCFOLDER
Apr 22 12:32:20 glo020-truservcomm-jhb1-001 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/dc-glo-mag235.service:12: WorkingDirectory= path is not absolute: ${DCFOLDER}
```

Trying to use `cd $DCFOLDER && docker-compose restart` as `ExecStart` command instead of `WorkingDirectory`:

```
Executable "cd" not found in path "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:
```

**Please note:**
When I disable `WorkingDirectory` and then use `cd`, when inspecting the `/var/log/syslog` the `ExecStartPre` echos actually give me the value of those variables (paths) as they are supposed to be.  So `ExecStartPre` executes fine.

### Issue

- I have custom `docker-compose.yml.*` files that are running *existing* containers, which need to be restarted/stopped/started.  Since the `docker-compose` service commands I want to use requires you to be **inside the directory where the `docker-compose.yml` is**, I need to be able to use `cd` or `WorkingDirectory` so that I can directly use `docker-compose start`.
- I have several instances of different sets of docker-compose containers (different folders) which are running, so I wanted to create a "template systemd" file which I can just specify the `EnvironmentFile` location.

In other words :

```
Example = each of these have their own Docker containers... so I want to create different systemd services for these:

/docker/folder/docker-compose.yml
/docker/folder2/docker-compose.yml
```

### Questions

I have a few questions here:

1. Can `WorkingDirectory` be used with an 'environment variable' and how? *As can be seen I tried PassEnvironment* but with an environment file.  Seems that I do not understand the *execution* of when `systemd` sets the Environment `WorkingDirectory`.  It looks like all of these "Service" commands expects static constant values...
2. `'cd' not found in path` - this one is weird because I thought I could simply *change directory* to the working directory (where the `docker-compose.yml` file is located so that I can run `docker-compose start/restart/stop`.
3. What is the actual use of `PassEnvironment`?
4. Finally - trying `$(which docker-compose) ps` as an example fails because, again like `WorkingDirectory` it seems to be expecting a 'constant value'.  I would have liked to use `$(which docker-compose)` instead of static locations.

Comment: Dang, I had a very similar question to yours, and was hoping that someone would answer you regarding the `WorkingDirectory` issue. All I can say is that `cd` does _not_ work because in most systems that's _not_ an external command, but a shell-specific instruction; to get those working, you'd have to call a shell; of course, if you do that, once the shell finishes, it won't be on that directory any longer...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn This was over a year ago, and cannot remember if or how I got this resolved.  I do use `sytemd` with `docker-compose`, so I got some things working eventually.  At the moment I am at work, so once I have time I will investigate the container content (docker-compose.yml files and `systemd` entries) to figure out if I used `WorkingDirectory` or not.  Please remind me again this week with an updated comment (I guess bookmark this question).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might just be as easy as

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "cd \"/path/${variable_subpath}/\";echo \"${PWD}\";"
```

and skip `WorkingDirectory` altogether. In most cases you can only get away with this hacky approach if it's a simple command or script.